# MATLAB imshow for 3D color image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a medical imaging matrix of size [200x200x200].

In order to display it, I am currently using [imshow3D](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41334-imshow3d--3d-imshow--new-version-released--see--imshow3dfull-) function, which is an excellent tool, built by Maysam Shahedi.
This tool displays the 3D image slice by slice, with mouse based slice browsing

In my current project, I generate an RGB image for each z-layer from the original input image. The output is a 3D color image of size [200x200x200x3] (each layer is now represented by 3 channels).

The imshow3D function works great on grayscale images. Is it possible to use it to display RGB images?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took a look at this nice [imshow3D function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41334-imshow3d--3d-imshow--new-version-released--see--imshow3dfull-) from Matlab FileExchange, and it is quite straight-forward to change it to allow working with a stack of RGB images.

The magic part of the function is

```
imshow(Img(:,:,S))
```

which displays the slice `S` of the image `Img`. We can simply change it to show all 3 channels of image `S` by changing this to `Img(:,:,S,:)`. The result will be of size *200-by-200-by-1-by-3*, while MATLAB expects RGB images to be of size *200-by-200-by-3*. Simply [`squeeze`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) this image to get the correct dimension. This results in:

```
imshow(squeeze(Img(:,:,S,:))
```

So to show RGB images, do a *search-and-replace* inside the function `imshow3D`, to replace all occurrences of `Img(:,:,S)` with `squeeze(Img(:,:,S,:))` and it works!

[image: result]

Comment: @drorco I would suggest messaging Maysam to add this in as a potential feature request. Detect how many dimensions there are in the image the adjust the `imshow` command accordingly.  It seems like a very useful feature.